# jQuery - error in receiving data

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my jQuery code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/beautician/accept_order",
    data: dataOrder,
    dataType: "text",
    method: "POST",
    success : function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

here is the PHP code:

```
public function accept_order(){
    echo "this is a test";
}
```

The output which I get in the console is: "success".

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: `this problem`. Where is the problem??

Comment: @bipen The problem is me not getting the desired string as output.

Comment: @PranavCBalan yup the url is definitely correct. the function is inside Beautician.php file

Comment: I would recommend using a tool like Fiddler to view the HTTP traffic so you can see the content that is returned by the Ajax POST.  I suspect you are getting a JSON object with a property that has "success".

Comment: Your function `accept_order` has no parameters while in `ajax request` you are passing `dataorder` in `data`..

Comment: somewhere in the PHP code you must examine the $_POST values and then call the accept_order() function in order to get your output. It would probably help to solve your problem if you show this part of the code as well.